# How to implement logic to create result array based on two arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this three JavaScript arrays:

```
  var arr1 = [
    {id:32, "isNormal":true},
    {id:4,  "isNormal":false}},
    {id:2,  "isNormal":false},
    {id:35, "isNormal":true},
    {id:44, "isNormal":false}]

  var arr2 = [
    {id:32, "isNormal":false},
    {id:4,  "isNormal":false}},
    {id:44, "isNormal":true},
    {id:35, "isNormal":true},
    {id:2,  "isNormal":true}]


var arrResult = [
   {externalId:32, startDate:currentDateTime, endDate:"null", "isNormal":false},
   {externalId:4,  startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":false}},
   {externalId:44, startDate:"null", endDate:"currentDateTime", "isNormal":true},
   {externalId:35, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":true},
   {externalId:2, startDate:"null", endDate:"currentDateTime", "isNormal":false}]
```

The arrays have same id.

I need to check isNormal property of the object in arr1 with appropriate property of the object (with same id) in arr2,

- if arr1.isNormal = true and arr2.isNormal = false write to arrResult.startDate  current date and time,
- if arr1.isNormal = false and arr2.isNormal = true write to arrResult.endDate  current date and time,
- otherwise do nothing.

Here the array result corresponding to arr1 and arr2. What is elegant way to implement this?

Comment: @Nishantjani I know i can implenent it using if and switch statments.But I want  to create somthing more elegant

Comment: I believe sorting the two arrays would reduce your run time complexity O(nlogn) as opposed to running two nested for loops O(n^2). Is that what you mean by elegant?

Comment: Post your current solution in question that works and we will see if this could be improved.

Comment: Will both arrays always have the same IDs?

Comment: @Nishant sorting by wich property?

Comment: You have two objects with id=32 in arr2. Is it correct?

Comment: Also do you want to change arr2 or create new array?

Comment: Are you stuck to using only arrays ? Using maps to store the data by ids could make the algorithm simpler, at the expense of memory and CPU. It is not clear from your question what you mean by "elegant" - and we don't have your current code to compare.

Comment: Second elements of both arrays have an extra bracket `}` In result the second value `currentTime` of the 1st element is unquoted.

Answer (score 1):

For checking if your `isNormals` are different I suggest using XOR operator `^`. Also it will be good to sort your arrays firstly.

Here are several examples, how you can do this.

```js
//I've fixed your data, because it is incorrect
var arr1 = [
    {id:32, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":true},
    {id:4,  startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":false},
    {id:2,  startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":false},
    {id:35, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":true},
    {id:44, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":false}]

  var arr2 = [
    {id:32, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":false},
    {id:4,  startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":false},
    {id:44, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":true},
    {id:35, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":true},
    {id:2, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", "isNormal":true}];

var sortFunction = function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
}

arr1.sort(sortFunction);
arr2.sort(sortFunction);

//This way:
var result = arr2.map(function(v, i) {
    var i1 = arr1[i].isNormal, 
        i2 = v.isNormal,
        obj = {id:arr1[i].id, isNormal:v.isNormal};
    
    obj.startDate = i1 ^ i2 && i1 ? 'currentDateTime' : 'null';
    obj.endDate = i1 ^ i2 && i2 ? 'currentDateTime' : 'null';
    return obj;
});
document.write('First: ', ['<pre>', JSON.stringify(result, 0, 1), '</pre>'].join(''));


//Or this way:
result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
   var i1 = arr1[i].isNormal,
       i2 = arr2[i].isNormal,
       obj = {id:arr1[i].id, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", isNormal:arr2[i].isNormal};

   if(i1 ^ i2 && i1) {
       obj.startDate = 'currentDateTime';
   } else if(i1 ^ i2 && i2) {
       obj.endDate = 'currentDateTime';
   }
   result.push(obj);
}
document.write('Second: ', ['<pre>', JSON.stringify(result, 0, 1), '</pre>'].join(''));


//Or this way:
var result = arr2.reduce(function(r, c, i) {
    var i1 = arr1[i].isNormal, 
        i2 = c.isNormal,
        obj = {id:arr1[i].id, startDate:"null", endDate:"null", isNormal:c.isNormal};

    if(i1 ^ i2 && i1) obj.startDate = 'currentDateTime';
    if(i1 ^ i2 && i2) obj.endDate = 'currentDateTime';
    
    return r.push(obj), r;
}, []);
document.write('Third: ', ['<pre>', JSON.stringify(result, 0, 1), '</pre>'].join(''));
```

Comment: I made some mistakes when I wrote the question.I updated my question please see update

Answer (score 1):

Here you go... Sometimes it's best to keep the code simple...

```
var arrResult = [];
//loop through the two arrays
for (var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i].id == arr2[j].id) {
            // if arr1.isNormal = true and arr2.isNormal = false write to arr2.startDate current date and time,
            if (arr1[i].isNormal && arr2[j].isNormal == false) {
                arrResult.push({externalId: arr1[i].id, startDate:new Date(), endDate:null, "isNormal":false})
            }
            //if arr1.isNormal = false and arr2.isNormal = true write to arr2.endDate current date and time,
            if (arr1[i].isNormal == false && arr2[j].isNormal) {
                arrResult.push({externalId: arr1[i].id, startDate:null, endDate:new Date(), "isNormal":true}) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bear with me, im not that good with jQuery but i did This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6w9ugq9/). it might help you.
so basically compare two ids, if they are same and isnormal:true do A and if they are the same and isnormal:false do B.

```
var res_arr = [];
for (var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
for (var j=0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if ( arr1[i].id == arr2[j].id && arr1[i].isNormal == arr2[j].isNormal == false) {
        res_arr.push({id: arr1[i].id, startDate:'currentDateTime', endDate:"null", "isNormal":false})
    }
    else if ( arr1[i].id == arr2[j].id && arr1[i].isNormal == arr2[j].isNormal == true) {
      res_arr.push({id: arr1[i].id, startDate:"null", endDate:'currentDateTime', "isNormal":true}) 
    }
}
}
```